# UNION result-set part is different than individual SELECT

Tags: mysql, union, mariadb, union-all

The query

```
(SELECT timest, `char`, exp_cnt AS XP FROM `charac` WHERE DATE(timest)='2017-01-30')
UNION
(SELECT timest, `char`, -exp_cnt AS XP FROM `charac` WHERE DATE(timest)=ADDDATE('2017-01-30',-1))
ORDER BY `char` ASC
LIMIT 50
```

gives me this result:
[image: UNION querry]

Where the date is `01-29`, the values should not be `0`, usually.
I try to debug it by copying-pasting and running the 2nd`SELECT`:

```
SELECT timest, `char`, -exp_cnt AS XP FROM `charac` WHERE DATE(timest)=ADDDATE('2017-01-30',-1)  
ORDER BY `char` ASC
```

And I get correct results!
[image: individual mysql select]

Why? I am confused. `UNION ALL` does not help.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `union all` rather than `union` unless you want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Second, you have a `limit` on the query.  So, your results are probably being generated, they are just further down the list and cut-off.

If you care about what happens on 2017-01-29, then sort the list by date and do the comparison that way:

```
(SELECT timest, `char`, exp_cnt AS XP
 FROM `charac`
 WHERE DATE(timest) = '2017-01-30'
) UNION ALL
(SELECT timest, `char`, -exp_cnt AS XP
 FROM `charac`
 WHERE DATE(timest) = ADDDATE('2017-01-30', -1)
)
ORDER BY timest ASC
LIMIT 50;
```

This may not be the final result you want, but you will at least see that all rows are accounted for.

If you don't want 0 values on the 29th, then explicitly put that into the query:

```
(SELECT timest, `char`, exp_cnt AS XP
 FROM `charac`
 WHERE DATE(timest) = '2017-01-30'
) UNION ALL
(SELECT timest, `char`, -exp_cnt AS XP
 FROM `charac`
 WHERE DATE(timest) = ADDDATE('2017-01-30', -1) AND
       exp_cnt <> 0
)
ORDER BY timest ASC
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: It is not the `LIMIT`. I have only 1 unique `char` per timestamp. Without `LIMIT`, I get same thing - `0`'s on the 29th day.

Comment: @ZygD . . . Your data appears to have those zero values.

Comment: Gordon - well, not in the vast majority of cases... Pls take a look at results of the individual select.

Comment: Again strange results, now after using the option with `exp_cnt <> 0`. Results that I get contain `0`'s ! On the same rows as the 01-29 dates. Some values are gone, however. Probably the ones, where there is actual 0 on the table.

Comment: @ZygD . . . Interesting.  They may look like zeros, but clearly are not.  Perhaps a floating point value that is very close to 0.

Comment: I have no experience in SQL, but i trust yours. Maybe this could be a bug in MariaDB?

Comment: @ZygD . . . I doubt it.  I'm just guessing that you don't fully understand the data.

Comment: Hey, I found the cause of this. My column `exp_cnt` can only contain unsigned values, so `-exp_cnt` was not even able to display correct results in `UNION`. (My workaround - `SUM(-exp_cnt)`) **But.... Is this normal?** UNION fails while SELECT works using the same `-exp_cnt` ?

Comment: Cast the value to a signed value if you need negative values.

Answer (score 1):

How many rows for each day?  I'll bet there are fewer than 50 for the 30th.  I'll bet the `UNION` got all the rows from the 30th, then some from the 29th.  That would explain it.

To further test my theory, run each `SELECT` in the `UNION` separately.

Another test:  Swap the two `SELECTs` in the `UNION`.  Now it may lose some of the rows from the 30th.

If you want the first 50 of both, use this pattern:

```
( SELECT ... ORDER BY timest LIMIT 50 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... ORDER BY timest LIMIT 50 )
ORDER BY timest LIMIT 50
```

If you need an `OFFSET`, too, it gets messier, but is possible:

For, say, the 3rd page:

- Inside, do `LIMIT 150` -- to be sure to get at least 150 from each (if available)
- Outside, do `LIMIT 100, 50` -- to get just the 3rd page *after* the `ORDER BY`.

But... There is still another issue.  Since `timest` is not unique, the 50 picked is not really deterministic.  So, you might want to change to `ORDER BY timest, id` or `ORDER BY timest, char`.